# I'm trying use Unity Ads to my game, but doesn't work

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ads, unityads

I made a game and I'm using Revmob already, but I would like use Unity Ads. I already modified my `AndroidManifest` following the instructions of the integration guide in Unity, but it is not showing the ads.

- In `AndroidManifest` I modified following what Unity says;
- I added a file that came with SDK (classes.jar);
- I added the lines that came with the SDK to ProGuard.

I tried to write

```
<meta-data android:vale="game ID number"/>
```

but it doesn't work. In the integration guide of Unity they have a SDK metadata with this code:

```
if(UnityAds.isReady()) {
PlayerMetaData playerMetaData = new PlayerMetaData(context);
playerMetaData.setServerId("example");
playerMetaData.commit();
UnityAds.show(activity);
}
```

but it doesn't work either because it isn't the same language used in Eclipse, right?

I think that it isn't showing because I don't put the game ID like the others Ad Network, but how can I put the game ID?

I'm using Eclipse Luna and Java 1.7. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to edit Unity Ads in Eclipse?
I use Unity Ads and i edit it on unity. not in eclipse.
what i did is i enable the Unity Ads

1) Open the Ads configuration window from Window > Services > Ads

[image]

2) Click the switch on the right-hand side to turn Ads on, then answer a few questions about the game you are making.

[image]

Ads are now enabled for your game.
For more check the full tutorial here.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityAdsHowTo.html

Comment: Yes, in Eclipse because my game was not made in Unity

Comment: Why are you using Unity Ads for your Native Project... why not use Google Ads(Admob) for that. Check this link: https://developers.google.com/ads/ it will save you some time.. if you just need to put an ads on your Game. Reverse Engineering an SDK that is not made for that platform is not an easy task...